# Core Data: Using a temporary property for progress?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios, core-data

I’m currently creating an iOS app that uploads files to a server. As multiple uploads can be queued and have metadata attached that I want to store persistently, I’m using Core Data to model and store uploads. I’m also using `NSFetchedResultsController` to display all uploads in a table view. So far so good.

I’m now implementing a progress indicator and that’s where I’m unsure if my implementation is really a good idea. I’ve added a `float` property to my model which gets updated by my upload controller as the upload progresses. I’m then updating my `UITableViewCell` subclass with the help of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` and this works pretty well. However, it doesn’t really make sense to actually **store** this property persistently, since uploads can’t be resumed if the app gets terminated. I’m only using the property to connect my upload controller and view controller. Is there a better way to do this without losing the convenience of `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: so your problem is linking the current 'progress' with its respected uitableviewcell? your way seems fair (but i could see how you think it might be overkill, but couldn't think of a better/faster way) , but a tag might also suffice (depends on the implementation i suppose)

Comment: Exactly. Using Core Data makes this really easy but I’m not sure if it is the most appropriate/elegant way to handle this. Also: I need to manually reset the progress property when the model gets fetched from the store after quitting the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you marker your property as Transient in the model editor it means that it wont be stored in the persistent file.

The property will reset to default each time the MO loads, though im unsure of the rules around at what point they will reset if you are not retaining specific instances of the MO's

This guy,  http://2pi.dk/tech/cocoa/transient_properties.html seems to know.